# I am not getting what this code does in perl

Tags: regex, perl

what does the following code mean in perl:

```
foreach (@a) {

    if ( $_ =~ m/active/ ) {

        s/ *//g;
        s/\r//;
        my @v = split(/\-/);
        $_cfg{$v[0]} = $v[1];   # Begin loading hash
    }
}
```

Comment: Specify which part you don't understand.

Comment: [`foreach`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) item in an [array called `@a`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors), [`if`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements) it [matches (`m//`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) "active" then do some [substitutions `s//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html), then [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) it into and array and put the resulting bits into a [hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explanation:

```
foreach (@a) {                  # loop on all elements of array @a
    if ( $_ =~ m/active/ ) {    # if current element contains 'active'
        s/ *//g;                # removes all spaces
        s/\r//;                 # remove carriage return
        my @v = split(/\-/);    # split on dash 
        $_cfg{$v[0]} = $v[1];   # populates the hash %_cfg where the key is 
                                # what there is before the first dash
                                # and value is what is between the first and the second dash
                                # or end of string
    }
}
```

If your array `@a` contains for example:

```
my @a = (
    'active-true',
    'this is not  - active'
    'whatever',
);
```

Then the hash `%_cfg` will contain:

```
%_cfg =
(
    active => 'true',
    thisisnot => 'active',
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me a lot and i was able to fix the issue in my script.

Answer (score 1):

Given an array `@a`:

- cycles through each of the elements, to see if they hold the text "active" as a substring.
- If it does:

  - removes all spaces
  - Removes all `\r` linefeeds.
  - creates a local array `@v` that splits the (modified) line on the `-` character.
  - Inserts into the hash %cfg a key value pair, where the 'key' is the first element of `@v` and the value is the second.

So given:
`fish-cab bage-42-moo-active`

Would end up with:
`$_cfg{'fish'} = "cabbage";`

`perl -MO=Deparse` can help understand this. The core thing to understand is `$_` - which is the implicit variable. It's set for each iteration of a loop to he current value, and is the default thing for certain functions to act against.  such as `split` or pattern replacements using `s/text/newtext/`.

Comment: That's true, but your example is wrong, it doesn't contain `active`.

Comment: OK, fair point. Amended :)

Answer (score 1):

here is the explanation:-

For each element in the array: `a`, if it matches 'active':-

1. remove all spaces in it.
2. remove the return character: '\r' in it
3. then, whatever is left in that element, split it with '-' and put the output of the split in an array
4. then, populate your _cfg hash table using the array v

I believe that each element in `a` is a key value pair separated by '-'